# User Group specific asset paths

Tags: plugin-development, assets, hook, assetfilemodel, modal

I've been doing some quite involved work on a site where we want to restrict user access to certain asset paths. Following the post at [Assets Folder: Images don't show up](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/assets-folder-images-dont-show-up/11869#11869) I was directed to the excellent add-on, [AssetSubfolderAccess](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/AssetSubfolderAccess)

After hitting a few bugs think have resolved but this only works in the Assets tab/are of the Control Panel. It does not seem to work within the Assets modal (eg when prompted on entry creation/edit). Is there a separate hook available for asset modals or can anybody suggest an alternative way of targetting specific asset paths at specific users?