# Uploading Assets - Problems

Tags: assets, upload

I've got a number of assets directories set up. One of them is having an issue where if you upload an image it doesn't appear in the control panel despite having been uploaded to the server. I checked and it's in the directory.

When uploading you see the upload progress bar, then that disappears and the image doesn't appear anywhere.

Not sure how to resolve this. Please advise.

Comment: This might not be it, but do you have ImageMagick enabled in php.ini on your server?

Comment: there are no problems uploading to other assets folders so I don't think that is the issue. PLus I have several other sites on the same server with no problems.

Comment: In that case, it could be a permissions issue. See [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/assets-folder-images-dont-show-up). If it's not that, I'm stumped.

Comment: It's not permissions, I've got the upload directories set to 777

Comment: Is your asset directory mapped correctly in the CP? (make sure Craft knows where the directory is).

Comment: @RitterKnight Yes it is. Craft can see existing files, files get uploaded but new ones don't show up in the upload/selection dialog

Comment: If you're using GD, then the image could be one that it doesn't support (or in a format that it doesn't support).  Try installing Imagick, which supports a much wider range of files/formats.  You can also check `craft/storage/runtime/logs` after uploading to see if it has any related errors.